# How do I do LISP (apply) in Dart?

Tags: dynamic, arguments, apply, dart

The [docs](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/) say to use `f.call.apply(arguments)`, but that seems to only work for object methods, not functions.

testapply.dart:

```dart
#!/usr/bin/env dart

say(a, b, c) {
    print("${a}!");
    print("${b}!");
    print("${c}!");
}

main() {
    var args = [1, 2, 3];
    say.call.apply(args);
}
```

Trace:

```dart
$ dart testapply.dart 
'/Users/andrew/Desktop/testapply.dart': Error: line 11 pos 2: Unresolved identifier 'Function 'say': static.'
    say.call.apply(args);
 ^
```

Is there a way to do LISP `(apply f args)` without using objects?

Alternatively, is there a way to dynamically wrap an arbitrary function in an object so that it can be applied using `f.call.apply(arguments)`?

Alternatively, can Dart curry?

Comment: Just as a hunch, do any of these work? 1. `say.apply(args)` 2. `say(*args)`

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Nope, thanks though.

Comment: Huge bummer. The star notation is what's used in Python and Ruby, so it was worth a try. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation page you refer to says,

> This functionality is not yet implemented, but is specified as part of version 0.07 of the Dart Programming Language Specification. Hopefully it will find its way into our implementations in due course, though it may be quite a while.

That may or may not be the issue...